# How to remove double quote from one particular column values in Pandas.to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing an small issue, I am filtering some data from the CSV file using Pandas. While saving new information as .csv using **Pandas.to_csv()** function to save my output. But csv file it is generating in that file there is one column data which set of number separated by comma. The info's of  all that column value is coming in string. I have added added image how the data coming after saving the output.

When I am opening the file manually by clicking over that file. Whole value is getting changed. Therefore, I would like to remove that double quote for all the values of that particular column. So that while opening the file manually data should not changed.

Could anyone help me with the issue.

```
df_filtered.to_csv("Demo2.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what the data in that column looks like in pandas (copy and paste into question, not an image!). If you run `df_filtered.dtypes`, I'm guessing that column will be object, which would mean you need to change it's type, but without seeing what the data in that column is, I don't know what that is

Comment: Yeah, Sure.. Please have a look. "33918,33919,33920,33921,33922,33923,33924,33925,33926,33927"

Comment: You should really edit your question to add those. I would imagine doing `df_filtered'ColName'] = df_filtered['ColName'].astype(int)` before exporting to csv would fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much..!! for the suggestion. My issue is resolved.